# gdb is miscounting args containing '#'

Tags: c, gdb, arguments

I run my program in gdb, withe the arguments `-b # +L -m`, but when I `break main`, argc is reported as 2 and the last argument available is `"-b"`. However, using `show args` in GDB gives me `Argument list to give program being debugged when it is started is "-b # +L -m"`, which is accurate.

`Starting program: /home/matt/`...`/args -b # +L -m`

`Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe028) at args.c:129`

Is # treated specially in an argument, even in GDB (not bash)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are running on Linux. gdb on Linux by default will invoke the shell to start your program. Therefore everything after the `#` is still being interpreted by the shell as a comment. You can change that behaviour in gdb by telling it not to use the shell to start the program via the `set startup-with-shell off` command.

Here is an example program that just prints `argc`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    return 0;
}
```

And here are the gdb runs with and without the shell receptively.

```
(gdb) r -b # +L -m
Starting program: /tmp/a.out -b # +L -m
2
[Inferior 1 (process 28385) exited normally]
(gdb) set startup-with-shell off
(gdb) r -b # +L -m
Starting program: /tmp/a.out -b # +L -m
5
[Inferior 1 (process 28443) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Refer to the [gdb manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html) for more details on program startup.

Comment: Since I plan for this program to be invoked from a command line, it would probably be a good idea to change the symbol used to mark that option to something else, eh? Or can I just escape it with a backslash?

Comment: Either would work. Or you could quote that symbol: `"#"`. But personally I would go with using a different symbol - otherwise it's inevitable that some user of the command will get it wrong.